# Wordpress Push Notifications Android App

Tags: android, wordpress, android-studio, onesignal

I am really struggeling to open Push Notifications sent by Wordpress to my Android Project. 
Test Notifications sent by OneSignal trigger the app to be opened, but when I publish an article on Wordpress, the notification comes through but on click the normal browser opens.

I have read the OneSignal AndroidSDK over and over again but I cannot seem to understand and implement it. When I use the code below the notifications from OneSignal Messaging System trigger the app to be opened.

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
                .init();

        // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your app if you have the user's email.
        // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
        // OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail);
    }
}
```

I was also looking at the `ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler`Tutorial by OneSignal but once the article is published it just opens the normal browser and not the app.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display your site within a webview of your app but this requires some customizations.

Turn OFF this switch in your wordpress plugin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOQ2q.jpg

You will need to add extra code to your wordpress site, read this article first on how to add custom code to your wordpress site: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq#section-where-should-the-code-be-placed-

Then follow the directions here on how to setup the custom code in order to show the notification inside a webview you added to your app: 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq#section-opening-web-and-mobile-notifications-in-the-browser-and-app

Comment: Thanks I already found those documentations and spoke to someone at OneSignal directly. Notifications are coming through now and trigger the app to open. I am still trying to figure out how to tell the code that it must open the respective article on click and not just the app